# Send output print via telegram

Tags: python, telegram

I have a question regarding sending a message via a telegram bot.

This is the code:

```
from ogn.client import AprsClient
from ogn.parser import parse, ParseError
import csv
import requests

def inRange_square(s, minLat, maxLat, minLon, maxLon, minAlt, maxAlt):
    if s.get('longitude', 0) < minLon or s['longitude'] > maxLon or s['latitude'] < minLat or s['latitude']>maxLat or s['altitude']<minAlt or s['altitude']>maxAlt :

        return False

    return True

def bot_sendtext(bot_message):

    ### Send text message
    bot_token = '698800548:AAH2GZl5cEYc1u1J-nn0izfBXJZm8nv-4uk'
    bot_chatID = '268013558'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    requests.get(send_text)


if __name__=="__main__":
    mydict = {}
    reader = csv.reader(open("aerei.csv", "r"))
    for rows in reader:
        k = rows[0].strip('"\'')
        v = rows[1].strip('"\'')
        mydict[k] = v

def processPlane(plane):
    if(inRange_square(plane, 46.1368, 46.1796, 8.8374, 8.9057, 210, 1000)):

        print("The plane is in range")
        ground_speed = round(plane.get('ground_speed', 0.0), 0)
        altitude = round(plane.get('altitude', 0.0), 0)
        print(mydict.get(plane.get('name')[3:]), (f"{ground_speed}"), (f"{altitude}"))
        bot_sendtext ( 'prova' )
    else:

        'odd'

def process_beacon(raw_message):
   try:
       beacon = parse(raw_message)
       #print('Received  {raw_message}'.format(**beacon))
       processPlane(beacon)
   except ParseError as e:
       #print('Error, {}'.format(e.message))
       print( raw_message )


client = AprsClient(aprs_user='N0CALL')
client.connect()

try:
    client.run(callback=process_beacon, autoreconnect=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nStop ogn gateway')
    client.disconnect()
```

Main code:

```
print(mydict.get(plane.get('name')[3:]), (f"{ground_speed}"), (f"{altitude}"))
```

The program print a value like this:

```
HBPEY 13.0 365.0
```

What I can not do is send the above outputs via telegram as the code below

```
bot_sendtext ( 'output_above' )
```

Hope result
Telegram bot print:

```
HBPEY 13.0 365.0
```

Can you tell me how I could do?
Thank you very much for helping
G

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the printed output as a string instead you can format it:

```
message = f"{mydict[plane['name'][3:]]} {ground_speed} {altitude}"
```

Then:

```
bot_sendtext(message)
```

edit: It would be easier to debug (and clearer to read) if the value lookup was done before the string formatting:

```
plane_name = mydict[plane['name'][3:]]
```

Then:

```
message = f"{plane_name} {ground_speed} {altitude}"
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I get this error: KeyError: 'name'. You know why?

Comment: Because in addition mydict there is plane: mydict.get(plane.get('name')                      {ground_speed} {altitude} work

Comment: @GionataDonati fixed

Comment: @GionataDonati you'll get a `KeyError` when `'name'` doesn't exist in a dictionary. Before you were using `get` which would return `None` if a key doesn't exist. But then you would get a `TypeError` when you tried to subscript the result.

Comment: the error is: KeyError: 'ICA4B7F68', i don't know why, the code don't remove the first 3 value from 'name'

Comment: Solved: message = f"{mydict[plane['name'][3:]]} {ground_speed} {altitude}"

Comment: @GionataDonati apologies, my mistake, fixed.